# Explicit join operations in SQL

Tags: sql, count, inner-join

I'm working on this query

> *Determine names of all the ships in the Ships table, which may be a linear (battle) Japanese ship having at least nine main guns with caliber less than 19 inches and displacement not more than 65 000 tons.*

The correct result is :

```
Musashi,
Yamato
```

my query is:

```
select   
    name
from 
    ships A
inner join 
    classes B on A.class = B.class
where 
    B.class = ANY (select class 
                   from classes
                   where country like 'Japan')
    and (numguns >= 9 and bore < 19)
```

and my result is right. But the application throws me the error:

> Your query returned the correct dataset on the first (available) database, but it returned incorrect dataset on the second checking database.
>   * Wrong number of records (less by 7)

database schema : http://img1.imagilive.com/0315/Snap_23-03-2015_at_151544.jpg

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I tried that, but throws me the same error

Comment: So what's different between the first and second databases? And...try rewriting the query so it doesn't have a WHERE clause, as in `SELECT NAME FROM SHIPS a INNER JOIN CLASSES b ON b.CLASS = a.CLASS AND b.COUNTRY = 'Japan' AND b.NUMGUNS >= 9 AND b.BORE < 19`.

Comment: there is only database but the application wants that I make a query best structured

Comment: The first thing I see is that you didn't include a filter for displacement <=65000.

Comment: when I try with this query :"select
case 
when name in 
(
select name from
(
select name,numguns,bore
from classes A
inner join ships B
on A.class=B.class
where numguns>=9
and bore <19

)AA
)
then name
end as name
from ships A
inner join classes B
on A.class=B.class
where B.country='Japan'
" I got null values

Comment: I executed the query : "select   
    name
from 
    ships A
inner join 
    classes B on A.class = B.class
where 
    B.class = ANY (select class 
                   from classes
                   where country like 'Japan')
    and (numguns >= 9 and bore < 19)

and displacement<=65000
" ..... but throws me the error: "Your query returned the correct dataset on the first (available) database, but it returned incorrect dataset on the second checking database.
* Wrong number of records (less by 9)"

Comment: You ***still haven't told us*** what actual, concrete database you're using .....

Comment: Also - given that [the Yamato class battleships of Japan had a full-load displacement of about 72,000 long tons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamato-class_battleship) (81,000 short tons) it wold appear that neither of the ships in this class (Yamato and Musashi)  should appear in your result list. I suspect that what's actually wanted is the Kongo and Nagato classes (six ships). Share and enjoy.

Comment: database schema : http://img1.imagilive.com/0315/Snap_23-03-2015_at_151544.jpg

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "May Be" means any of the search conditions could be NULL which is needed to be considered

```
select name from 
 (select name, s.class, numguns, bore, displacement, type, country
  from classes c, ships s where c.class=s.class) a

where (country='japan' or country is null) 
and (numguns>=9 or numguns is null)     
and (bore<19 or bore is null) and (displacement<=65000 or displacement is null) 
and (type='bb' or type is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct S.name
FROM   Ships as S INNER JOIN Classes as C
ON     S.class = C.class
WHERE  (C.country = 'Japan' or C.country is null)
and (C.type = 'bb' or C.type is null)
and (numGuns >= 9  or numGuns is null)
and (bore < 19  or bore is null)
and (displacement <= 65000  or displacement is null)
```